# Ajax get external JS without loading it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a report page that should contains the version of a JS library we are using.
I'm using Jquery ajax for that
my code :

```
    function loadAppLogic() {
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: url,
                 crossDomain: true,
                 dataType: 'jsonp',
                 success: function(data) {
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log(data);
               }
           });
    }
```

The problem with that code is that it actually load the script contains in the url (and thus produce errors due to the absence of bootstraping)

I don't need to load the file, i just want to be able to get it in a "text way" to read the second line (that contains the version number)

Do you know what can i do ?

Comment: So you're trying to access a `JSON` file and access a key within it?

Comment: Not a JSON a JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in your AJAX call `dataType: 'text'` which will prevent the pre-processing of the script

Comment: This works inside the same domain but not for crossDomain (but it answer the question :) )